# Sicher sein + etwas?

Tags: difference, expression

1. Welche der folgenden Formulierungen sind korrekt?
2. Worin unterscheiden sie sich?
3. Wenn alle drei korrekt sind, kann ich *meine Wahl* durch ein anderes Substantiv ersetzen?

> a1. Ich bin mir meiner Wahl sicher.
>   a2. Ich bin meiner Wahl sicher.
>
> b. Ich bin mir mit meiner Wahl sicher.
>
> c. Ich bin mit meiner Wahl sicher.

Comment: Wieso sollte man etwas durch ein x-beliebiges Wort ersetzen können?

Comment: Einzelne Fragen sind besser. Jemand kann jetzt eine Antwort nur zu einer der Fragen geschrieben und kann nicht schlecht sein (aber die Frage bleibt unbeantwortet).

Answer (score 2):

> a1: Ich bin mir meiner Wahl sicher.

Ist korrekt und bedeutet, dass die Person sich sicher ist, die richtige Wahl getroffen zu haben. Der Ausdruck *sich jemandes/einer Sache sicher sein* verlangt den Genitiv ([Quelle](http://canoonet.eu/blog/2008/02/26/152/) )

Dann kann *meine Wahl* durch andere Substantive ersetzt werden, aber dadurch ändert sich die Bedeutung des Satzes.

- Ich bin mir meiner Entscheidung sicher.
- Ich bin mir meiner Beziehung sicher.
- Ich bin mir meiner Gefühle sicher.

> c. Ich bin mit meiner Wahl sicher

Dieser Satz bedeutet, dass die Person durch die Wahl, die sie getroffen hat, in Sicherheit ist. Ich glaub, der Satz ist grammatikalisch richtig, aber trotzdem würde ich eher sagen:

> "Ich bin durch/trotz/wegen meiner Wahl sicher"

Comment: b hört sich auch richtig an, wenn auch unnötig lang

Comment: [Der Ausdruck lautet _sich jemandes/einer Sache sicher sein_. Er verlangt den Genitiv.](http://canoo.net/blog/2008/02/26/152/)

Comment: "Ich bin mir mit meiner Freundin nicht so sicher." Wie willst du das mit Genitiv sagen. "Richtig hört sich nur 1a an" Kann nicht sein. "Ich bin mit der Warnweste sicher." ist ein grammatisch richtiger Satz. Er hat exat dasselbe Muster wie c. C klingt also richtig. Nur wenn du c wie a1 interpretierst, kann es dir evtl. aufstossen. Das sollte dann präziser in der Antwort verarbeitet werden.

Comment: @Emanual, stimmt, der Satz im OP ist uneindeutig. Ich pass meine Antwort an.